# MySQL DELETE with JOIN on condition

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables; products, variants, and stock {simplified}

PRODUCTS
id
name
discontinued (ENUM: 0 or 1)
etc

VARIANTS
id
product_id
colour
size

STOCK
id
variant_id
branch_id

When the user selects to discontinue the PRODUCT I set the discontinued flag to 1. That's fine, but I want to delete the PRODUCT and VARIANTS records altogether if there is no STOCK record of the product. Obviously I can do this using a SELECT query first in PHP but I would like to do it in one mySQL query. This is what I have so far, but it is returning an error from mySQL:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM prod_lines, 
  JOIN variants ON variants.lineid = prod_lines.id
  WHERE prod_lines.id = '$lineid' AND
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM stock WHERE stock.variantid = variants.id) = 0";
```

Can anybody out there help me come up with the right solution? Maybe there is a better way that doesn't even involve a subquery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Choose `prod_lines , variants` OR `prod lines JOIN variants`, that comma shouldn't be there.

Comment: thanks for that, you are right. It didn't make my query work but needed fixing all the same :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the `product_line` table in your query is the `PRODUCTS` table you describe in the beginning of your post.

```sql
DELETE prod_lines.*  -- you must specify which table you are deleting from, because there are several tables in the FROM clause
FROM prod_lines
JOIN variants ON variants.lineid = prod_lines.id
LEFT JOIN stock ON stock.variantid = variants.id
WHERE prod_lines.id = @lineid -- your "$lineid" variable here
AND stock.id IS NULL; -- selects only items with no match in the "stock" table
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40a21

Comment: yes you assume correctly. I was trying to simplify it and forgot to change it in the code example. I will try your solution and let you know

Comment: Edited the query to match the tables and columns names inside your `$query`.

Comment: Spot on, works a treat and I've learned something. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,the downside is though you have to have two php variables here and also an nested query that you may not be ok with

```
   DELETE FROM (select COUNT(id) countstock FROM stock s,variants v WHERE s.variantid = v.id and v.productid='$lineid') prod 
    where prod.countstock>1 and prod.productid='$lineid'
```